How to install Debian Linux on a MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2012 for testing (dual boot)? How to back up for case of destroying OS X system?
My MacBook Pro 13" (Mid 2012) is struggling hard with what I'd like it to do (many many open Browser-Tabs, Microsoft Office, Signal Messenger and some more open applications) and I want to test, if Linux might be the better choice for the old machine.
Configuration:
MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2012

2,9 GHz Dual-Core Intel i7
16 GB RAM
SSD 870 QVO 1 TB
Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
Mac OS X 10.15.7

I would like to install Linux (e. g. Debian) for testing without compromising my still running OS X system, so I think I need a Dual Boot solution, right?
I don't have experience with the hardware and software topics - bootloader, ...
With OS X it was always very easy to boot from another partition or external Firewire HD.
Is there any risk to break my existing OS X system when trying to install Linux (bootloader, ...)?
Usually I would create a disk image of the current system (and data) partition of my OS X on an external hard disk which I could use for a backup later.
But I wonder if that is enough. Do I need to save any other partition or information to get back to the original state in case of failure?
EDIT: Storage hardware configuration: diskutil list internal
% diskutil list internal                                            
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         500.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s3
 
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume Daten                   441.5 GB   disk1s1
 
/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Ohne Titel - Daten      458.1 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume MBP                     11.3 GB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 26.2 MB    disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                526.8 MB   disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      5.4 GB     disk2s5

EDIT 2 - core of my question:
p. s. I think my most important question is: could the setup for a Linux+OSX dual boot installation damage something so hard that I would not be able to just boot from an OS X firewire HD, partition the internal SSD and restore a clone (backup) of my working (slow) previous OS X?
(It is crucial for me to stay "productive" with this machine and due to a very difficult personal situation I do not have time to fix and repair for some days (and during this time not be able to work with my old OS X, as long as there is no new working system set up.)

I would use a virtual machine using VMware Fusion (or similar).  But you might well prefer the answer from @BillHorvath

Might be helpful if you could post the output from the command diskutil list internal.

@Gilby with a virtual machine I will not get info about the maximum possible performance, right? But as performance is my main issue with OS X 10.15, I need to test real performance

@DavidAnderson thank you - I added the info inmy question

Do you intend to replace disk0s3 with Debian? Or have you not yet allocated space for the Debian installation?

no, there is no space allocated so far for linux - I would cut something off from Volume "Daten". (MBP is the MacOS X system partition including home directories)

With a machine from that era, you can boot into Linux from a USB storage device without touching the existing configuration. Here are instructions for doing so with Ubuntu; you may be able to find a comparable version of these instructions for Debian.

thank you! That sounds interesting. I'll give it a try.
Would there be any difference, if I created a partition on the internal SSD and copied the content from the USB Stick on this partition? I still wonder if USB could reduce the performance of my test setup..

I'd actually have to do research to know whether OSX would recognize each partition as bootable, but assuming that's the case, it would likely be more performant. That's just a guess, however.

In 2021 I did what you're contemplating on my "late 2011" 17" MBP. For me - like you - I figured I didn't have much to lose if it all went wrong. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (since upgraded to 22.04), and it went very well for me. I'm still very much enjoying this machine, and it's still quite responsive. I kept a record of all the steps I went through, and posted that to one of my GitHub repos.
I won't elaborate any further now, but feel free to post something on GitHub - or here if you prefer - if you have questions or hit any snags.

thank you very much for sharing your experience. Indeed, I HAVE MUCH TO LOSE, as this is my slow but productive machine and due to very difficult personal circumstances,  I do not have time at the moment to spend days for re-configuring or fiddling with a new OS, while the old one is unsuable... anyway, the current one is more and more annoying me due to its slowness..

@MostlyHarmless: Oh... sorry I mis-read your situation. In that case, I can't recommend my "conversion" to you. I got away with it fine, but a) my machine is different than yours, and b) Apple randomly (it seems) changes things that might have a huge impact on the conversion.

thank you - no need to apologize, I think I did not make this situation clear in my original question. At first I only want a quick test, if Linux might really be faster than my OS X 10.15. However I think that a clean install of OS X 10.15 could also improve a lot, but I hesitate trying because it would take a lot of time to setup all necessary programs and settings and if I invest this time, probably Linux would be more future proof

p. s. I think my most important question is: could the setup for a Linux+OSX dual boot installation damage something so hard that I would not be able to just boot from a OS X firewire HD, partition the internal SSD and restore a clone (backup) of my working (slow) previous OS X?

@MostlyHarmless: Yes - I understand...  Unfortunately I cannot answer that question. And given the proprietary nature of Apple systems, I'm not sure that anyone can. My approach to all of my Apple systems (except my old 2011 model) is this: I never upgrade the OS, and I keep them for only 3 years. Frankly, I despise Apple's forced obsolescence, and I despise Apple for their policy. If there were a better alternative, I'd buy it instead of Apple.

I do not have your Mac. I used a 2013 iMac running Catalina to test this answer. Some of the testing was done using two different VirtualBox virtual machines.
Backup Important Files
Minimally, you should make sure important files are copied to an external location which can be disconnected from the Mac while installing Debian. You can also use Time Machine or the Disk Utility to do backups. The are also various third party applications which can used backup your internal drive.
Create Space for Debian

Note: The sizes you see when partitioning will differ from the sizes shown in the following images. Also, the container identifier numbering may be different.

The instructions below outline how to use the Disk Utility to create a new ExFAT partition. Later during the installation of Debian, this partition will be replaced with an ext4 formatted partition where Debian will be installed.
Open the Disk Utility and then press the key combination command ⌘+2 to "Show All Devices", as shown below. Highlight the container containing the "Daten" volume, then select the "Partition" button.

In the popup shown below, select the "Partition" button.
[
With the "Daten" partition highlighted as shown below, select the "+" button.

Choose the size for the new APFS partition. This will also be the approximate size of the partition which will hold Debian. Set the name to "TBD", as shown below. When finished, select the "Apply" button.

Note: After installing Debian and some updates, I found about 24 GB of disk space was used.


In the popup shown below, select the "Partition" button.

Hopefully, you will get the "Operation successful" popup shown below. Select the "Done" button.

Highlight the container containing the "TBD" volume, as shown below, then select the "Erase" button.

Choose a format of ExFAT, as shown below, then select the "Erase" button.

Hopefully, you will get the popup shown below. Select the "Done" button.

The result is shown below.

You can quit the Disk Utility.
Create Debian USB Flash Drive Installer
There are many Debian ISO installers to choose from. I chose Live Gnome.
The debian-live-12.7.0-amd64-gnome.iso file was download to my Mac.
You can use the dd command to copy the ISO file to the USB flash drive. If you are unfamiliar with the dd command, then I suggest you download and use the Etcher application to copy the ISO file to the USB flash drive.
Start the Debian installer
With the USB flash drive pulled into the Mac, start the Mac and immediately hold down the option until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear. Select to boot from the USB flash drive.
From Grub, I chose the default, which booted to the Debian Live desktop. I executed the installer application from Debian Live.
Partitioning the Drive

Note: The sizes you see when installing may differ from the sizes shown in the following images.

When you reach the window shown below, select "Manual partitioning", then select the "Next" button.

Highlight the /dev/sda4 partition labeled "TBD", then select the "Delete" button.

Highlight "Free Space", then select the "Create" button.

Change the mount point to /, then select the "OK" button.

Highlight the /dev/sda1 partition labeled "EFI", then select the "Edit" button.

Change the mount point to /boot/efi, then select the "OK" button.

Select the "Next" button.

When the popup shown below appears, select the "OK" button.

Note: For Macs, a 300 MiB EFI system partition is used then the sector size of the drive is 4096 bytes. Your drive has a 512 byte sector size and correctly has an EFI system partition size of 200 MiB (209.7 MB). The warning message can be ignored.


Getting Debian to Appear in the Mac Startup Manager
After you are finished installing Debian, you will need to enter commands in either a macOS or Debian terminal to make Debian appear in the Mac Startup Manager. (The Mac Startup Manager appears when you hold down the option at startup.)
The commands to enter from macOS are given below.
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
pushd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
mkdir -p boot
cp debian/grubx64.efi boot/bootx64.efi
popd
diskutil unmount disk0s1

The commands to enter from Debian are given below.
pushd /boot/efi/EFI
sudo mkdir -p boot
sudo cp debian/grubx64.efi boot/bootx64.efi
popd


wow, thank you very much for testing this and for the detailed instructions!

p. s. I'll try this out as soon as I can (might take some time) and will give you a feedback, if it worked
